# Google Analytics: are variables overwrited when I push a new value?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Let's suppose I'm using the following to indentify some users:

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'id', '<?php echo time() ?>', 1]);
```

If I put this snippet on all of my pages, will the id be overwritten every time?

**OBS:** *I'm using a Visitor Scope (1) custom variable.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will be overwritten when you use the same slot in the same scope, plus there will be problems when you use page level scope variables and other scopes with the same slot on the same page (see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#setup - Section "Use Caution When Mixing Different Variable Types").

Comment: Well, in my case...? If the snippet is in the header of every HTML, will the user get a new ID every time he goes from one page to another?

Comment: Unless time has stopped, yes (which means that the data in your report might change retroactively). You'd need to store  the id in a cookie (or simply pull the visitor id  from the google cookie) and set it only when it has not been set before (i.e. if there is no cookie. Keep in mind that a visitor level variable persists for multiple visits as long as the google cookie has not been deleted).